# Add a zero to a zip code in a csv file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a quick way to append a zero to some highlighted cells in my csv file so I don't have to go one by one?

Should be 01234
Instead it is showing 1234

Since all the zip codes are different I cant just do a simple find and replace. TY

Comment: You can sort by cell color and and apply =0&[original number cell reference] to a helper column. Overwrite the original column with helper column and  sort it back to the original format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Open the csv in excel
2. Insert a mask at ZipCode column using `=TEXT(A1, "00000")`
3. Save as csv, ignoring the fact that you'll loose the formulas (this will preserve the results in the csv file)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using cell formatting option `Zip Code`.

Select the column/cells containing zip codes.
Right click -> `Format Cells`
`Number` tab -> `Special` category
And select `Zip Code` type.